# How to add an image upload to a wordpress options panel

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Been building a theme in Wordpress 3.0.4

I've come to the stage where I want to be able to add image uploading in the options page. I've tried most of the tutorials around but none of them seem to work.

Would love a working solution if anyone has one.

Comment: Please migrate this question to: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far and away the best 'example' options panel I've found is this one: http://wptheming.com/2010/11/thematic-options-panel-v2/  -- it was initially made for the Thematic framework, but there's also a version which is usable in any theme. [here: http://wptheming.com/2010/12/options-framework/ ]

Has pretty much everything you could need - media uploads, colour pickers, dropdowns, textareas, single-line inputs, checkboxes, select boxes etc.